# Windows Cortona Not openable

Tags: performance, cortana

My windows Cortona, for some reason, after a while of the computer turning on, cannot activate. I click the ask me anything and it does nothing. The start button also doesn't work. I can open things on the taskbar and everything but just not Cortona and the Start button. This renders me useless when opening other apps! Help!

Answer (score 0):

try to set language of cortana to Uk English in setting